# TypeError: list.forEach is not a function at service.buildList [as project]

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest

I've been thinking about a problem all morning. I'm noobie to Typescript and Angular. I'm need a call to my back API, but when filling the data in an array to display it, it is giving me an rawRegistrosList *undefined* error.

TypeError: rawRegistrosList.forEach is not a function at ConsultaService.buildConsultaList [as project (eval at  (app.js:391:1), :35:26)

I'm getting a little crazy. Sorry for my english too...

**consulta.service.ts**

```
private buildConsultaList(res: any){ // res has data when debugging
    this.registros = [];
    var rawRegistrosList: any[] = res.data; 
    rawRegistrosList.forEach(rawElement => { // error here, in rawRegistrosList.forEach
      var registro : Consulta = new Consulta();
      registro.cifEmpresa = rawElement.cifEmpresa;
      registro.nombreEmpresa = rawElement.nombreEmpresa;
      registro.ccc = rawElement.ccc;
      registro.afiliado = rawElement.afiliado;
      registro.nombreCompleto = rawElement.nombreCompleto;
      registro.identTrab = rawElement.identTrab;
      registro.altaMC = rawElement.altaMc;
      
      this.registros.push(registro);    
    });
    
    console.log("1 this.registro");
    console.log(this.registros);   
    return this.registros; 
  }
```

**consulta.json:**

{
"data": {
"idTrabajador": 1,
"cifEmpresa": "20855585",
"nombreEmpresa": "Poleomenta SL",
"ccc": "08/254891/22",
"nombre": "Pepito",
"nombreCompleto": null,
"primerApellido": "Grillo",
"segundoApellido": "Grillado",
"identTrab": null,
"afiliado": "Si",
"altMC": "No",
"razonSocial": "Razón Social 1",
"nifEmpresa": "5697413J",
"direccion": "Calle desengaño 21",
"localidad": "Alicante",
"cp": "032120",
"ubg": "",
"tipoIpf": null,
"ipf": null
},
"backendError": null,
"httpResponse": true,
"totalCount": 0
}

Could someone tell me what is happening and if I am initializing it correctly?

Comment: Where does res come from? How is it fetched? Can you show it?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that **consulta.json** is what is contained in `res`.

`res.data` does not contain `entity` or even a list. IT contains a single element.

Try the following instead:

```
var rawRegistrosList: any[] = [];
rawRegistrosList.push(res.data);
```

Then do your `rawRegistrosList.forEach`

Comment: I also tried to remove it but it did not solve anything.

Comment: Changed my answer. Also do a console.log(res); and add the expanded object to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If consulta.json is the response then isnt an array, is an Object!
You cant iterate Objects with javascript array methods.

You are recieving:

```
{
    data: {...} // object
}
```

You need an array:

```
{
    data: [....] // array
}
```